# Function to remove classes and add new classes in to iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to know whether these function will work . since my html is inside of a iframe .

```
function removeClass(){
 $("#testjqtable").removeClass("mce-item-table");
}

function addClass(){
 $("#testjqtable").toggleClass("ui-table,ui-table-reflow");
}
```

since I tried it it gave an error

Comment: This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe - your function names are not interfering with jQuery's so don't worry about changing them.

Comment: maybe names of functions are interfering with jQuery function names. change your functions name.

Comment: isn't it because it is inside of a iframe and I need to say that "hey capture the id inside of the iframe " ?

Comment: @ChamZ - you can run into some issues when dealing with iframes (mainly  the same origin policy). If the iframe source is on the same domain then there are some great solutions in the question I linked to.